# How to make the make the main node in center

Tags: latex, tikz

Following [tree](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/family-tree/) I create a figure. However, the main node is not in the centre. Also, the text within nodes seems so packed. Any suggestions?

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
     \usepackage[edges]{forest}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
    \tikzset{every shadow/.style={shadow xshift=5pt,shadow yshift=-5pt}}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      man/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=gray!20},
      woman/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=gray!20,rounded corners=.8ex},
      grandchild/.style={grow=down,xshift=1em,anchor=west,
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
      first/.style={level distance=6ex},
      second/.style={level distance=12ex},
      third/.style={level distance=18ex},
      fourth/.style={level distance=24ex},
      fourth/.style={level distance=24ex},
      fifth/.style={level distance=29ex},
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=15em}]
        % Parents
        \coordinate
          child[grow=0ex] {node[man,anchor=south]{Challenges:Blockchain-based Digital Twins}}
          child[grow=down,level distance=0ex]
        [edge from parent fork down]
        child{node[man]
        {Technical Challenges}
          child[grandchild,first] {node[woman]{High-fidelity Models}}
          child[grandchild,second] {node[woman]{Data-related Issues}}
          child[grandchild,third] {node[woman] {Model Challenges}}
          child[grandchild,fourth] {node[woman] {Uncertain Events}}
        child[grandchild,fifth] {node[woman] {Interoperability}}
          }
           child{node[man]
          {Logistical Challenges}
          child[grandchild,first] {node[woman]{Standardization Barriers}}
          child[grandchild,second] {node[woman]{Scattered Ownership of Data}}
          child[grandchild,third] {node[woman] {Infrastructure Cost}}
          child[grandchild,fourth] {node[woman] {Skepticism in Blockchain}}
          }
        child{node[man]
          {Social Challenges}
          child[grandchild,first] {node[woman]{Ethical and Moral Issues}}
          child[grandchild,second] {node[woman]{Environmental Issues}}
          child[grandchild,third] {node[woman] {Lack of Collaboration}}
          child[grandchild,fourth] {node[woman] {Lack of Sharing Sensitive Information}}
          };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked example needs to use this `\ccordinate` hack because it is not a typical tree with one parent node.

Hwever in your case you can simply start with a node, which then will automatically be centred:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{every shadow/.style={shadow xshift=5pt,shadow yshift=-5pt}}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  man/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=gray!20},
  woman/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=gray!20,rounded corners=.8ex},
  grandchild/.style={grow=down,xshift=1em,anchor=west,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
  first/.style={level distance=6ex},
  second/.style={level distance=12ex},
  third/.style={level distance=18ex},
  fourth/.style={level distance=24ex},
  fourth/.style={level distance=24ex},
  fifth/.style={level distance=29ex},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=15em}]
    % Parents
    \node[man] {Challenges:Blockchain-based Digital Twins}
      child[grow=down,level distance=2ex]
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child{node[man]
    {Technical Challenges}
      child[grandchild,first] {node[woman]{High-fidelity Models}}
      child[grandchild,second] {node[woman]{Data-related Issues}}
      child[grandchild,third] {node[woman] {Model Challenges}}
      child[grandchild,fourth] {node[woman] {Uncertain Events}}
    child[grandchild,fifth] {node[woman] {Interoperability}}
      }
       child{node[man]
      {Logistical Challenges}
      child[grandchild,first] {node[woman]{Standardization Barriers}}
      child[grandchild,second] {node[woman]{Scattered Ownership of Data}}
      child[grandchild,third] {node[woman] {Infrastructure Cost}}
      child[grandchild,fourth] {node[woman] {Skepticism in Blockchain}}
      }
    child{node[man]
      {Social Challenges}
      child[grandchild,first] {node[woman]{Ethical and Moral Issues}}
      child[grandchild,second] {node[woman]{Environmental Issues}}
      child[grandchild,third] {node[woman] {Lack of Collaboration}}
      child[grandchild,fourth] {node[woman] {Lack of Sharing Sensitive Information}}
      };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]